# Не могу запустить приложение expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Пытался запустить дефолтное приложение на expo, но что-то пошло не так

PS C:\Windows\System32\FirstApp> npm start

@ start C:\Windows\System32\FirstApp expo start

EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\System32\FirstApp.expo' Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\System32\FirstApp.expo' at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:921:3) at Object.module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:102:15) at dotExpoProjectDirectory (C:@expo\xdl@57.9.28\src\ProjectSettings.ts:133:6) at projectSettingsJsonFile (C:@expo\xdl@57.9.28\src\ProjectSettings.ts:41:15) at Object.setAsync (C:@expo\xdl@57.9.28\src\ProjectSettings.ts:91:18) ands\start.ts:134:25) at normalizeOptionsAsync (C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:129:9) at C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:350:41 at C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:314:12 at Command. (C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:79:13) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @ start: expo start npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\HP-Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-07T17_47_32_229Z-debug.log PS C:\Windows\System32\FirstApp> expo start Сбой выполнения программы expo: Указанному файлу не сопоставлено ни одно приложение для выполн ения данной операциистрока:1 знак:1

expo start
строка:1 знак:1

expo start

- CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Что мне сделать, что бы исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо разрешить выполнение скриптов через PowerShell

1. Открываем PowerShell от админа.
2. `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
3. На вопрос отвечаем: A (Да для всех)

[Подробнее](https://winnote.ru/security/160-windows-powershell-vypolnenie-scenariev-otklyucheno-v-etoy-sisteme.html)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно команда выглядит так:
npm run start

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]